# Redirección luego de autenticación en sitio Xampp PHP

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

Estoy intentando realizar el direccionamiento a un sitio, previa validación de usuario y contraseña en local (Xampp) pero no sé porque al momento de hacer el proceso me lo está enviando no a la ruta "admin/admin.php" sino al index.php de la carpeta raíz del servidor local por lo cual me termina redireccionando al "dashboard" de Xampp. El sitio utiliza PHP versión 5.5.38. porque necesito montar el sitio primero para poder ver bien como funciona para ver como está e irlo actualizando.

```
if (isset($_POST['u_identification']) && isset($_POST['u_pass'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['u_identification'];
  $password=$_POST['u_pass'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "admin/admin.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "admin.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysqli_select_db($conexion, $database_conexion);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT u_id, u_identification, u_pass, u_rol,u_name,u_lastname FROM users WHERE (u_rol=0 OR u_rol=4 OR u_rol=5 OR u_rol=6) AND u_identification= binary '%s' AND u_pass= binary '%s' AND u_status=1",
    get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $loginUsername : addslashes($loginUsername), get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $password : addslashes($password)); 

  $LoginRS = mysqli_query($conexion, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
  $row_LoginRS = mysqli_fetch_assoc($LoginRS);
  $loginFoundUser = mysqli_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser==1) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";


    $_SESSION['MM_UserIdAdmin'] = $row_LoginRS['u_id'];
      $_SESSION['MM_UsernameAdmin'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroupAdmin'] = $loginStrGroup;
      $_SESSION['MM_UserRol'] = $row_LoginRS['u_rol'];    
      $_SESSION['MM_FullName'] = $row_LoginRS['u_name']." ".$row_LoginRS['u_lastname']; 

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
    }else if($loginFoundUser==0){
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
    }  
}
```

Aclaración: el sitio con este mismo código tal cual como está ahí funciona correctamente en versiones PHP superiores y en el sitio de producción funciona correctamente con la misma versión de PHP que se indica arriba, no sé que podría revisar.

Answer (score 0):

Estas empleando mal el **header**, *header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );* no esta tomando ninguna ruta, ya que la variable **$MM_redirectLoginSuccess** esta fuera de las comillas (asignación), debería de ser así:

```js
header("Location: $MM_redirectLoginSuccess");
exit;
```

**NOTA:** Recuerda agregar **exit;** despues del header